# How to exclude certain pages from the below rewrite condition

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to exclude /blog/wp-admin/ and /blog/wp-login.php from

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://examplesite.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So that those will skip and stay on https and everything else will pass through.
In other words the below should not be affected by the rule:

```
_https://examplesite.com/blog/wp-admin/
_https://examplesite.com/blog/wp-login.php
```

How can this be achieved?
I have tried adding the below as a second condition but it doesn't do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(wp-admin/|wp-login\.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me ok. However if the are browsing using the `/blog` in the URL then it needs to be in the condition also. Try this rule below how I have it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog/)?(wp-admin/?$|wp-login\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://examplesite.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```